# Is the following sentence correct and natural?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

> currently a second-year Master of Web Intelligence and Data Science's student

Is the above grammatically correct and natural sounding?

What is the difference between 'master of' and 'master's in' ?

here is the hole paragraph

I am Brahim Louardi, currently a second-year Master of Web Intelligence and Data Science's student in the double exchange program between Sidi Mohamed Ben Abdellah University in Morocco and Sorbonne Paris Nord University

Comment: I would lose the "'s" on the end of Science, unless the course title is "... Data Sciences" in which case lose the apostrophe!

Comment: A "data sciences student". The apostrophe is wrong.

Comment: We don't do proof reading. This question will be closed.

Comment: I'm not asking for proofreading, but I have a lot of confusion regarding whether to use 'master of' or 'master's in.

Comment: @LouardiBrahim - Master's is short for "master's degree"

Comment: If you had a question about a specific point of grammar, you should have asked that instead of 'is this sentence correct?'. The qualification is usually "Master of XXX", but you can say "I am studying for a Master's degree in XXX".

Comment: @KateBunting's suggestion is best: While we might use "doctor" as a title ("I am a Doctor of Medieval Literature"), we don't typically do so with the master's degree. It's best to apply the term to the degree rather than yourself.

Comment: @AndyBonner - Master of Arts?

Comment: @KateBunting Hm, I can't see myself saying "I'm a Master of Arts." Of course for that reason I can't see myself saying "I'm a Doctor of Arts" either, but I might imagine *someone* saying it. The OP's underlying issue is we often say "I'm a master's student," but that's an informal usage that IMO doesn't pair well with formally stating your intended degree.

Comment: @AndyBonner - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Arts

Comment: @KateBunting Sure; in case it's unclear, I'm supporting your suggestion. Of course the phrase "Master of Arts" is used of the degree. I just question how comfortable it is in a sentence that starts with "I am a," even if it goes on to add "... student" after the full degree title.

Comment: @AndyBonner - OK. Yes. I had misunderstood you as claiming that _Master of..._ was unidiomatic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have some minor improvements that I would make.

1. As others have mentioned, you should not use the apostrophe for *Sciences*. [The apostrophe would mean it is possessive.](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/apostrophe_introduction.html)
2. I think the phrase *double exchange* should be [hyphenated as a compound adjective](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/hyphen_use.html).
3. The sentence is long, which makes it difficult to mentally process. For clarity, you might consider breaking it into two sentences. This is a matter of personal style, however.

> I am Brahim Louardi, currently a second-year Master of Web Intelligence and Data Sciences student. I am enrolled in the double-exchange program between Sidi Mohamed Ben Abdellah University in Morocco and Sorbonne Paris Nord University.

Comment: Please don't encourage requests for proofreading, which is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry @KateBunting - I did not realize that was a rule. I'm new and tried to answer a question. Should I delete it?

Comment: The question itself will soon be closed, as it has 3 'close' votes already.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [what's on and off topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the future. As for this Q&A, it's in an awkward state in that OP edited to focus on a specific issue that you didn't cover in this answer.

Comment: Yes, I just found the rules and I'm familiarizing myself with them after Kate's comment. Thanks!